# Example of a quadratic programming problem with no optimal solution on vertices?

Tags: linear-programming, quadratic-programming

Is there a way to write a quadratic programming problem with

1. two variables
2. bounded, nonempty feasible region
3. linear constraints

and yet have none of the vertices of the region optimize the objective function?

Comment: consider the squared distance from a point in a square on a plane to a point slightly above the center of the square? (above in the direction orthogonal to the plane)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer:

max xy

subject to 2x+2y<=10, x,y>=0

The optimal cannot lie on a vertex because then you would be multiplying by 0.